# Hibernation issues for windows 7 computer

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I have a rather new custom built pc with an asus mobo (6 months).

The computer has issues waking up after hibernation. The power button refuses to wake the computer after hibernation/sleep mode from Win 7.

The only way to get it to start again is to pull the motherboard power cable (the cable that runs from the PSU to the motherboard) out and plug it back in.

Is this a sign of a bad power supply or is it a sign of a bios issue as described in this thread: [How does hibernation work?](https://superuser.com/questions/39578/how-does-hibernation-work/39598#39598)

Comment: THis may indicate that the PSU does not supply your system in stand-by mode with enough voltage. If your BIOS have an option like "ErP/EuP" then enable it (makes your system EU power consumption compliant). It should minimize the stand-by power usage. May be this is enough.

Comment: I'll first say that I haven't seen a PSU made in the last 5+ years that doesn't support the stand-by voltages needed for deep sleep states (unless it's broken).  All hardware and software must support hibernation for it to work properly.  Perhaps try unplugging all unnecessary peripheral devices (all but mouse/keyboard/monitor), and disable all non-MS startup software via `MSConfig`.  If it hibernates as expected, then you know it's most likely either a device or a piece of 3rd party software preventing a proper wakeup from hibernation.

Comment: Also, have you double checked your BIOS settings to ensure proper setup for hibernation and other sleep states?  Perhaps try a different PSU.  Or try a PSU tester, or multi-meter to check the expected voltages?